# HTTP request didn't response 404 not found

Tags: linux, http, bitbucket, http-status-code-404

I have installed the clamak antivirus. but I need a new version clamtk_5.20-1_all.deb.I try to solve this problem but I can't.
the error message is given below

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/dave_theunsub/clamtk/downloads/clamtk_5.20-1_all.deb
--2019-06-08 04:35:46--  https://bitbucket.org/dave_theunsub/clamtk/downloads/clamtk_5.20-1_all.deb
Resolving bitbucket.org (bitbucket.org)... 18.205.93.1, 18.205.93.2, 18.205.93.0, ...
Connecting to bitbucket.org (bitbucket.org)|18.205.93.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-06-08 04:35:47 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I checked the network connection it's good.what's the problem of this? and how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: `404 Not Found` explains it - you've requested a file that isn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I found in their official web page, they moved into `Gitlab`.
Please choose which file you want to download from this page:
[official download page](https://gitlab.com/dave_m/clamtk/wikis/Downloads)

But for any reason, if you insist on using `Bitbucket`, then please review [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/davem_/clamtk).